# Java Not Finding EditText set by .setId()

Tags: java, android

My app dynamically inflates some XML and adds it to an already existing layout that is nested in a scroll view. In each of the layouts that is inflated, I have an EditText that I need to get the text of later. I get a NullPointerException because it cannot find the editText. Anyways, this is my loop that grabs the text of the EditTexts:

BTW the +1000 is so it doesnt interfere with Items that were set using .setId()

```
for(i=1;i<numOfItems;i++){
               etIndex = (EditText)findViewById(numOfItems+1000);
                listOptions.add(etIndex.getText().toString());
           }
```

It is returning a NullPointerException because the etIndex is empty when I try to get the text.

Here is the code where I inflate the EditText:

```
etItem = (EditText)newView.findViewById(R.id.etItem);
                etItem.setId(numOfItems+1000);
                etItem.setHint("List Item " + numOfItems);
```

Comment: where do you set id for edittext?

Comment: The code where you inflate the EditTexts, also run in a loop?

Comment: Since you're changing the value of `i` inside your loop, why are you using `numOfItems` to get the id here? `etIndex = (EditText)findViewById(numOfItems+1000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
etIndex = (EditText)findViewById(numOfItems+1000);
```

to

```
etIndex = (EditText)findViewById(i+1000);
```

The last index there is equals `numOfItems - 1` so when you use `numOfItems` you simply get `NullPointer` instead of `EditText`.